# How can I get Kerberos SSO for spring to work behind a load balancer across multiple domains?

Tags: spring-security, load-balancing, kerberos, kerberos-delegation, spring-security-kerberos

We have an application which is SSO enabled and run into the below url **https://abcd.test.com**, now we have created a new application which is spring kerberos enabled(with keytab file) and has a different url (**https://xyz.test.com**). Now We will put a load balancer in front of **abcd.test.com** and if any user goes **https://abcd.test.com/serach** then it should redirect to the new application url https://xyz.test.com and SSO should happen. Is it possible that after LB redirect to the new url when user type  https://abcd.test.com/serach the SSO occurs?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the client (OS) is able to retrieve a Kerberos service ticket from the KDC for service 'xyz.test.com' this should work.